# Excluding values from sets of data

Tags: r

I'm trying to write a code that will exclude certain factors from sets of data/numbers.

I have written the following:

```
x <- c("1407741214DAG359", "2211682828DAG359", "1304410201DAG359", "0908700465DAG36", "0909700565G379")

y <- c("1407741214DAG359", "2211682828DAG359", "1304410201DAG359", "0","0")
```

Here i wish to exclude the values that contain `DAG36` and `G379`

I tried writing the following:

```
newdata.x <- x[ x != "DAG36", "G379" ]
```

However, the code only seems to exclude values that exclusively contains: DAG36 and G379 and not any value containing either `DAG36` or `G379`.

Would any of you be able to help me?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for `grep("DAG36|G379",x,value=TRUE,invert=TRUE)`.

Answer (score 3):

What you are searching for is `grep()` or `grepl()`. Both functions search for a pattern in a given string or vector of strings, in your case.

The pattern you are looking for is `DAG36` and `G379`. You can express this in [regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions) like `DAG36|G379`.

```
grep("DAG36|G379", x)
# [1] 4 5 

grepl("DAG36|G379", x)
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE
```

As you see, these two functions come down to the same thing, really, and can be used interchangeably. Now you can use indexing to replace the relevant strings with a zero:

```
x[ grepl("DAG36|G379", x) ] <- 0

x <- x[ grepl("DAG36|G379", x) ]                    # Easier version of removing relevant strings
x <- grep("DAG36|G379", x, invert = T, value = T)   # More direct version
```

Comment: More robust to use `TRUE` and `FALSE` rather than `F` and `T`. There is nothing stopping a person from writing `T <- FALSE` in a script.